# How can I use GitLab CI only?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have repositories in BitBucket and I am satisfied and do not want to change it to another cvs.

But I want to use some free CI service for my projects.

Things I tried:

- PhpCI, but PhpCI is bad supported
- Jenkins, but it is too complicated for me

That's why I started researching Gitlab CI.

I saw that CI is a part of gitlab (https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/).
But maybe somehow I can use just CI and do not use another features.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think that Gitlab CI is very tightly integrated with Gitlab. You could probably setup Gitlab mirror for your Bitbucket repo but with all the controls and build info in Gitlab it just doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use GitLab CI without GitLab, but no one forces you to use any of other GitLab features if you don't want to.

Git is distributed and you can have your source pushed to multiple destinations.

Just define it in your project's `.git/config` as another destination for push, for example:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git
    pushurl = git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git
    pushurl = ssh://git@gitlab.yourdomain/user/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Then add `.gitlab-ci.yml`, push, and GitLab CI will run, while your source will be both in BitBucket and GitLab (which you will use only for checking the CI pipeline).

Comment: So, the solution for my case is next:

Comment: So, the solution for my case is next:
1) Install full GitLab
2) Add mirror for my bitbucket repo
3) Configure GitLab CI

Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. By the way, you don't need to install GitLab CI if you don't have experience, you can just spin up a [Dockerized GitLab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab).